# Error while compiling: "Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, texmaker

I know that a lot of people have already done this question but, I've tried everything said in the answers but nothing works!
I'm trying to use TeXMaker 4.4.1 and MikTeX 2.9 but, when I try to compile a pdf immediately I get the message on the screen:
"Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
I don't understand anything about it, so I'd like an explanation step by step...
(I heard about PATH, what is this? This can solve my problem?)

Comment: You can inform TeXmaker where to find the executable files from MikTeX. Go to Options>Configure and insert the full path for the commans `latex` and `pdflatex`. For example, in Windows could be similar to `Program Files/...`

Comment: Was this issue resolved?