# Won't compile: error pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Tags: compiling

I'm new to LaTeX and I haven't succesfully compiled my code to a pdf-file yet.
I have both MiKTeX and Texmaker installed but when I try to compile, a window pops up with the message:

> 'Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex'.

The code I try to compile is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

I have seen multiple people here with the same question, but I haven't found an answer that works. Anybody an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! In which order did you install MiKTeX and TeXmaker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241515/error-while-compiling-could-not-start-the-command-pdflatex-synctex-1-intera?rq=1